# Boolean field disabled after migration an Infopath form from 2007 to 2010

Tags: infopath

We have a complex form build on top of a set of xsd files.

The form is used as the association and initiation form of a custom visual studio workflow.

Everything was working as expected on the 2007 platform.

Now, the platform has been migrated to the 2010 version. But the boolean field stopped to works. In fact, the HTML dom of the generated form has explicitely the **disabled** attribute on the generated checkbox :

```
<SPAN style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" class="a1_8F0mPmkZMpYOqfxX_0 j_8F0mPmkZMpYOqfxX_0 a2_8F0mPmkZMpYOqfxX_0" onmouseover="return LeafControl.OnWrappingSpanMouseOver(this, event);" onmouseout="return LeafControl.OnWrappingSpanMouseOut(this, event);">
    <INPUT disabled onblur="return (CheckBox.OnBlur(this, event));" id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_XmlFormControl_V1_I1_C5 class="a0_8F0mPmkZMpYOqfxX_0 m_8F0mPmkZMpYOqfxX_0" onfocus="return (CheckBox.OnFocus(this, event));" title="" tabIndex=0 value="" type=checkbox OriginalId="V1_I1_C5" FormId="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_XmlFormControl" ViewDataNode="6" direction="ltr" wrapped="true" ScriptClass="CheckBox">
</SPAN>
```

What can cause this boolean field to be disabled???

FYI, the boolean field is part of an XSD schema :

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.corporate.com/moss/common/shortwfschema" xmlns:shortwf="http://schemas.corporate.com/moss/common/shortwfschema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xsd:element name="Shortwf" type="xsd:boolean">
     </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

It then has been imported in the form by using "Add new"-->"Import complete xml schema" on the root of the form schema.

This resulted in the apparition of the field `shortwf:Shortwf` in my main form.

Then I've added a simple checkbox, bound to this field (I've also try with other kind of controls, with no success).

[image]

I've also tried to create a section, bound to this field, but the section does not even appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Can't explain why, but if I remove the workflow association, and if I re-associate it, the boolean field started to works correctly.</s>

The only major drawback of this technique is that I loose all the workflow history

**Edit**: I find the actual root of the issue, and was able to fix it.

The workflow has been updated last year. This update introduced the new boolean field.

However, the workflow association data did not included this boolean field (in its xml definition). This caused InfoPath 2010 to ignore this field and disable the checkbox.

So the actual workaround was to "patch" the association data to include the desired value of this field. I've played a bit with PowerShell:

```
# Get the workflow association (in my case, the only workflow on my library)
$web = Get-SPWeb http://server/sites/web
$lib = $web.Lists["My Library"]
$wf = $lib.WorkflowAssociations[0]

# patch the association data
$wf.AssociationData = $wf.AssociationData.Replace("</otherfield>","</otherfield><shortwf:Shortwf>false</shortwf:Shortwf>")

# save it
$lib.WorkflowAssociations.Update($wf)
```

The association update is not very academic, but it's a one shot script and that was enough in my case.

I believe I should have created a new v2 workflow, in order to maintain the old workflow instances but I was lucky enough to be able to stop all running workflows